# Авторизация пользователя в Symfony 3

Tags: symfony3

Необходимо реализовать простую авторизацию пользователя.
Сейчас работает вот с такими настройками security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
       in_memory:
           memory:
               users:
                   admin:
                       password: admin
                       roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Мне нужно сделать чтобы проверка логина и пароля происходила по моей схеме. Т.е. все пользователи хранятся в другой базе в таблице users. Вся работа с этой таблицей заключается только в проверке логина и пароля и получения емаила юзера. Проверка данных из формы логина это первый и последний раз когда будет использоваться эта таблица.

Прописал роутинг

```
login_check:
    path: /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Security:check }
```

но проверка проходит как бы мимо этого экшена. В checkAction я пытаюсь вывести простой текст и остановить выполнение скрипта, но открывается главная страница.

Comment: Это нормальное поведение для стандартного form_login:
UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener получает запрос и проверяет его на соответствие `check_path` и пытается выполнить аутентификацию. В случае успеха, формируется ответ и обработка запроса прекращается, т.е. до контроллера дело не доходит.